# how to use regex pattern in java for numbers

Tags: java, regex

i want to check that is there a pattern of number in a string

i'm trying to find out that a number is correct or not , for example i use this code but it return false but i expect return true :

`System.out.println(Pattern.matches("1*3", "123"));`

Comment: `1*3` is regexpese for "any number (even zero) of 1 characters, followed by precisely a single 3". "123" obviously does not match this pattern. So, what did you expect, here? Your question makes it seem like you expect java to find a crystal ball and divine out of sheer nothingness that you want "1*3" to somehow match whatever you are thinking of that counts as a 'number' and are surprised that it's not working. But surely that's not happening here - your question lacks detail. Edit it to clarify. Include some strings you intend to match and some that should not.